# UISearchController not showing. iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I'm working on pushing a 1.1 update for my app and I have been unable to get `UISearchBar` to show and work on my ViewController in iOS 9. The app is written is swift.

Here is the ListViewController

[ListViewController.swift](https://github.com/Froz3n907/TA-News-Beta/blob/master/TeamAppleNews/ListViewController.swift)

Seems like no matter what I add it won't show. I've tried numerous tutorials. 
 Also having an issue with pull to refresh hanging.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, Austin! It's a bit hard to help without more information, but I am going to give it a try. Are you trying to add a searchBarController or a searchBar. Many of the more modern apps put the search bar in the navigation bar. Here is the code to do that:

Add `UISearchBarDelegate` to the class (after the : ).

Create this variable : `lazy var searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))`

Add this code to your viewDidLoad:

```
searchBar.delegate = self
searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

You can then add code to the method, `func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar){ }` and to the method `func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) { }`

**For the refresh control:** at the end of the refresh function, call `self.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()`

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a go

Comment: As far as the refresh spinner, what do you mean by "it's hanging"?

Comment: It doesn't dismiss

Comment: Check out my updated answer. If this works for you please click on the checkmark to mark it as the right answer and click on the up arrow to help me out!